# find the count of tasktype(taskcount,bugcount) with filter condition,

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to find the count of tasktype(taskcount,bugcount) with filter condition, but when i write this code, it ignored the filter condition and gives me count from full table. please help me with right code.

```
    SELECT A.[projectname], 
       A.[projectid], 
       A.[releasename], 
       A.[releaseid], 
       A.[sprintname], 
       A.[sprintid], 
       A.issuenumber, 
       dt.tasktype, 
       Sprint.sprintcompletedate date, 
       CASE 
         WHEN dt.tasktype = 'Task' THEN Count(a.tasktype) 
       END                       taskcount, 
       CASE 
         WHEN dt.tasktype = 'Bug' THEN Count(a.tasktype) 
       END                       Bugcount 
FROM   cqm_details AS A 
       INNER JOIN cqm_details dt 
               ON a.issuenumber = dt.parentkey 
       INNER JOIN dbo.cqm_sprints Sprint 
               ON Sprint.sprintid = A.sprintid 
WHERE  A.tasktype = 'Story' 
       AND A.taskstatus IN ( 'Closed', 'Done', 'Completed' ) 
       AND a.projectid = 106 
       AND Sprint.sprintcompletedate BETWEEN '2020-05-01' AND '2020-05-30' 
GROUP  BY A.[projectname], 
          A.[projectid], 
          A.[releasename], 
          A.[releaseid], 
          A.[sprintname], 
          A.[sprintid], 
          A.issuenumber, 
          dt.tasktype, 
          Sprint.sprintcompletedate
```

Comment: Wrap the `CASE` expression with `SUM()` instead. `SUM(dt.tasktype = 'Task' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS taskcount`

Comment: Not helping, it's still giving me full table count, instead of the filtered applied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to replicate the issue mentioned but the results look fine.

Please find the db<>fiddle [**here**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d66fe860d7a5c7de95ff7b9683212f3e) with sample data.

Please change/add the sample data and provide the db<>fiddle URL if the results are not ok.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to get count for each tasktype on a separate line?

```
SELECT A.[projectname], 
       A.[projectid], 
       A.[releasename], 
       A.[releaseid], 
       A.[sprintname], 
       A.[sprintid], 
       A.issuenumber, 
       dt.tasktype, 
       Sprint.sprintcompletedate date, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN a.tasktype IN ('Task','Bug') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER(PARTITION BY a.tasktype) AS taskbugcount
FROM   cqm_details AS A 
       INNER JOIN cqm_details dt 
               ON a.issuenumber = dt.parentkey 
       INNER JOIN dbo.cqm_sprints Sprint 
               ON Sprint.sprintid = A.sprintid 
WHERE  A.tasktype = 'Story' 
       AND A.taskstatus IN ( 'Closed', 'Done', 'Completed' ) 
       AND a.projectid = 106 
       AND Sprint.sprintcompletedate BETWEEN '2020-05-01' AND '2020-05-30'
```

Or have it grouped for the issue?

```
SELECT A.[projectname], 
       A.[projectid], 
       A.[releasename], 
       A.[releaseid], 
       A.[sprintname], 
       A.[sprintid], 
       A.issuenumber, 
       dt.tasktype, 
       Sprint.sprintcompletedate date, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN a.tasktype IN ('Task','Bug') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) taskbugcount                    Bugcount 
FROM   cqm_details AS A 
       INNER JOIN cqm_details dt 
               ON a.issuenumber = dt.parentkey 
       INNER JOIN dbo.cqm_sprints Sprint 
               ON Sprint.sprintid = A.sprintid 
WHERE  A.tasktype = 'Story' 
       AND A.taskstatus IN ( 'Closed', 'Done', 'Completed' ) 
       AND a.projectid = 106 
       AND Sprint.sprintcompletedate BETWEEN '2020-05-01' AND '2020-05-30' 
GROUP  BY A.[projectname], 
          A.[projectid], 
          A.[releasename], 
          A.[releaseid], 
          A.[sprintname], 
          A.[sprintid], 
          A.issuenumber, 
          dt.tasktype, 
          Sprint.sprintcompletedate
```

If you are trying to get a separate count for both task and bug, just copy the logic and check the tasktype against "task" and "bug" separately.